# Add jar dependency to gradle task without actually including its classes to the output

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, javac, gradlew

I currently use gradle build script that looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies { 
    compile files('libs/android.jar')
}
```

I need now to build a jar that doesn't include classes from android.jar

Any ideas?

Comment: seems like it's compileOnly ('provided' is deprecated), doc https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use feature variant to model "optional" dependencies: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/feature_variants.html

Answer (score 0):

So, the jar that is built this way contains only classes built from java files. To include them, use Shadow. If you want them just to be compile-time classpath, use compileClasspath property of java source set.